# Get dataframe cell value using outer

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to get values from a dataframe, but when I try to get the cell value R gives an entire column instead. How do I fix this?

```
outer(row.names(temp_df),colnames(temp_df),function(x,y){paste(x,",",y,",",temp_df[x,y])})
#      [,1]              
# [1,] "x , y , c(2, 1)" 
# [2,] "x2 , y , c(2, 1)"
temp_df<-data.frame(c(1,2),c(3,4))
temp_df<-data.frame(c(1,2),c(3,4))
colnames(temp_df)<-c("c1","c2")
row.names(temp_df)<-c("x","x2")
outer(row.names(temp_df),colnames(temp_df),function(x,y){paste(x,",",y,",",temp_df[x,y])})
#      [,1]                      [,2]                     
# [1,] "x , c1 , c(1, 2, 1, 2)"  "x , c2 , c(3, 4, 3, 4)" 
# [2,] "x2 , c1 , c(1, 2, 1, 2)" "x2 , c2 , c(3, 4, 3, 4)"
temp_df
#    c1 c2
# x   1  3
# x2  2  4
```

My end goal is:

```
# x,y,2
# x2,y,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that x and y in your case are not single values, but vectors (row and colnames essentially). As far as i understood, you are then trying to slice the temp_df providing vectors, but not single values.
I might have not understood what you are trying to do, but i hope this helps:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

temp_df %>% mutate(name=rownames(temp_df)) %>% 
            melt(id.vars="name") %>%      
            apply(1,function(i){
                 return(paste(i,collapse=","))
            })

#"x,c1,1"  "x2,c1,2" "x,c2,3"  "x2,c2,4"
```